# NGINX `if` "erases" headers?

Tags: nginx

Using NGINX (1.24.0 and prior versions), it seems that just simply using an `if` statement (for its design purpose) erases any headers previously added within the location:

```
location /test {
    add_header "Test" "some-value";

    if ($sent_http_test = "some-value") {
        return 201 https://some.url/login;
    }

    // else
    proxy_pass https://myupstream.biz/...;
}
```

In this case, 200 is returned (so the `if` is not entered), and the `Test` header is present on the response. Same outcome if the `add_header` is moved to the parent block:

```
add_header "Test" "some-value";

location /test {
    if ($sent_http_test = "some-value") {
        return 201 https://some.url/login;
    }

    // else
    proxy_pass https://myupstream.biz/...;
}
```

Passing the `Test` header from the client causes NGINX to return 201 (so *request* headers are visible to `if`). Using `map` does not fix the problem:

```
# in http block
map $sent_http_test $test_is_some_value {
    some-value yes;
    default    no;
}

# in server block
location /test {
    add_header "Test" "some-value";
    add_header "Test2" $test_is_some_value;

    if ($test_is_some_value = "yes") {
        return 201 https://some.url/login;
    }

    // else
    proxy_pass https://myupstream.biz/...;
}
```

In this case, both the `Test` and `Test2` headers show up in the non-201 response, but `Test2` is set to `no`, indicating that `map` does not / cannot look at headers added with `add_header`.

Finally, using `return` alone, and trying to return a `set_header` value in the body does not work:

```
location /test {
    add_header "Test" "some-value";

    return 201 "test=$sent_http_test";
}
```

This results in a 201 response with a body of `test=`.

---

In summary, it appears that `if` does not only cannot see headers added with `add_header`, but it actively erases them so they're not returned. I understand that headers are an array and NGINX does not preserve them e.g. if you `add_header` in the `server` block, and then `add_header` in the `location` block, the one added in the `server` block will not be preserved (nor will any others added prior). Does `if` and `return` behave in the same way?

Comment: Your question is confusing because you have request headers and response headers with the same name and value. I cannot reproduce the problem with add_header not being returned with the return 201. But I can confirm that add_header does not appear to set an `$sent_http_` variable when the `return` is processed.

Comment: You're right, I'll clarify...

Comment: ...done. Updated occurrences of `$http_` to be `$sent_http_`. The problems are the same. (Aside: I absolutely hate that comments are non-editable after 5min.) I added further clarification.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "actively erases" when the response headers are definitely present, despite not appearing in the `$sent` variables when `if` and `return` are processed. There is a history of quirks with `if` and `return` - they live in the [same module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html) and tend to be evaluated early which means some other Nginx features get circumvented.

Comment: By "erased" I really just mean they are not usable by `if` or `return`. But this is not documented (as far as I can tell), so I was surprised to find this issue. You say they're evaluated early, which would explain this issue.